# Call a C++ constructor from an Objective-C class

Tags: c++, objective-c

How can I call a C++ constructor from inside an Objective-C class?

```
class CppClass {
public:
    CppClass(int arg1, const std::string& arg2): _arg1(arg1), _arg2(arg2) { }

    // ...
private:
    int _arg1; std::string _arg2;
};

@interface ObjC: NSObject {
    CppClass _cppClass;
}
@end

@implementation ObjC

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if ( self )
    {
         // what is the syntax to call CppClass::CppClass(5, "hello") on _cppClass?
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When I end up in a situation where the default constructor doesn't cut it, I make the instance variable a pointer and then use `new` in the `init` method and `delete` in the `dealloc` method.

It's a relatively recent thing that default constructors are called at all for Objective-C instance variables, actually.

There is no specification of the Objective-C language, let alone a specification of the Objective-C++ extension. Apple does publish a document called [The Objective-C Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/ObjC.pdf), but it barely mentions C++, so you're often left on your own when you need to clarify something unobvious. The guys at the [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) [mailing list](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/mailman/listinfo/cfe-dev) often know better, though.

Comment: to use new it has to be a pointer not a stack based allocation

Comment: @stackmonster, indeed. That's what I meant by "I make the instance variable a pointer".

Answer (score 5):

If you need a stack-based C++ class as an ivar of your obj-c class, then you cannot pass any arguments to the constructor. The class will be constructed as part of your obj-c object's allocation. You could use the assignment operator in your `-init`, or you could modify your embedded object in some other way (e.g. using member functions, etc).

If the class absolutely needs to be constructed with arguments, then you cannot use a stack-based object and must instead allocate it on the heap with `new` (and then delete it with `delete` in your `-dealloc`).

Comment: @nielsbot: Seems like a more complicated way of just defining a subclass where the default constructor passes predefined values to the superclass's constructor.

Comment: Is there an "official" Objective C link or book somewhere that explains this?

Comment: @syvex, I believe there is no Objective-C specification, let alone an Objective-C++ specification, at least for Apple's implementation of it. You can gather small pieces of information on [Clang's website](http://clang.llvm.org/) and have most of your questions answered on the Clang mailing list. Some smaller parts of the language have specifications (blocks and ARC do), but I have yet to see the language's.

Answer (score 3):

If you're already using C++ in your ObjC, might as well make it a smart pointer, so you don't have to worry about adding the cleanup bits.

```
#include <memory>

@interface ObjC: NSObject {
    std::unique_ptr<CppClass> _cppClass;
}
@end

@implementation ObjC

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if ( self )
    {
         _cppClass.reset(new CppClass(5, "hello"));
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for kicks--I found a partial solution using templates, but I doubt you'll get much "real-world" mileage with it...

```
template <int X, const char Y[]>
class CPPClass
{
    int _x;
    const char * _string ;

public:
    CPPClass();
};

template <int X, const char Y[]>
CPPClass<X, Y>::CPPClass()
: _x(X)
, _string(Y)
{

}


extern const char kHelloWorld[] = "hello world";

@interface MyObject : NSObject
{
    CPPClass<5, kHelloWorld> thing;
}

@end
```

Note that the `int` template parameter can be a literal in place, but the `const char[]` template parameter must be declared in a variable with external linkeage.. (according to *clang*)

Comment: also, you might even end up in C++ typecasting hell. yay.

Comment: Worked for a string in a variable

Comment: Yes, `const char*` values are considered integral (because pointers are integral). It would not work with an `std::string` though. It works for integers of any size, pointers from global values that have their address taken, and values from `enum`s.

Comment: Also, you don't need the `"C"` part of `extern "C"` for your `kHelloWorld` variable. External linkage only means the variable needs to be visible through your whole program, it doesn't need to meet C linkage specifications. `Const` global variables default to `static`, that's why you need `extern`; without the `const` modifier, you don't need the `extern` either.

Comment: @zneak 1st comment: that's exactly what the compiler told me... 2nd comment: I changed me code... This is all silliness though :)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is create a wrapper for `CppClass`, and provide constructor arguments in that wrapper, like:

```
class CppClass {
public:
    CppClass(int arg1, const std::string& arg2): _arg1(arg1), _arg2(arg2) { }

    // ...
private:
    int _arg1; std::string _arg2;
};

namespace {

struct CppClassWrapper {
    CppClass innerClass { 5, "hello" };
};

}

@interface ObjC: NSObject {
    CppClassWrapper _cppWrapper;
}
@end

@implementation ObjC

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if ( self )
    {
         // use _cppWrapper.innerClass
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Answer (score -1):

I havent tried this but for fun Im going to just riff on this:

First this looks wrong:

```
@interface ObjC: NSObject {
  CppClass _cppClass;
}
@end
```

Look you are declaring a stack based class in the interface of an obj c class.

Try

```
CppClass *_cppClass;
```

Then as long as you have included the CppClass in your file

You should since obj C interops with both C and C++ be able to 
create an instance with

```
_cppClass = new CppClass(pass constructor args here
```

I wouldnt recommed putting the C++ class in the same file

In an obj C project you need a .mm file - not sure if declarations for CPP are included in that.
Proly not.

So you need a separate header and impl for your C++ class as you normally would then just include the CPP header and code CPP in your obj class as normal.

I could be way off here, havent tried it but, obj C seems to gracefully be able to call C and C++ as long as you stick to the rules.